# Difficulty understanding memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, ram

I am trying to understand the different aspects of memory allocation in C. In the example below, I am calculating the mean of an array. I have defined one function in which the return is an `int = 4`, and the second in which the return is a `double = 4.57`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int getMean(int arr[], int size);
double getMean2(int arr[], int size);

int main()
{
    int mean1;
    double mean2;
    int array[7] = {1,3,5,7,5,4,7};
    mean1 = getMean(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
    printf(" Mean 1 = %d", mean1);
    mean2 = getMean2(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
    printf("\n Mean 2 = %.2f", mean2);

    return 0;
}

int getMean(int arr[], int size) {
   int i;
   printf("\n");
   int sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       {
        sum += arr[i];
       }
   return sum/size;
}

double getMean2(int arr[], int size) {
   int i;
   printf("\n");
   double sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       {
        sum += arr[i];
       }
   return sum/size;
}
```

In the case of the mean function returning an int, is the same memory allocation in RAM still used as in the function returning the double? Or is it still able to perform the calculation using less RAM?

When the int function is performing the calculation, does it still have to store the number as a double, before returning the int?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Memory for what? The array? Then yes, what you pass are *pointers*, arrays can't be passed.

Comment: `int` usually takes up 4 bytes while `double` takes up 8, if that's what you meant.

Comment: This depends on your compiler and platform. You should look at the generated assembly if you want to know the details.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. When the int function is performing the calculation, does it still have to store the number as a double, before returning the int?

Comment: @Sjoseph If you can clarify the question, then please [edit] it.

Comment: Why should the `int` function use a `double` anywhere? I don't see any doubles in its code :o

Comment: I am wondering what is happening "under the hood". The answer of the calculation is a double? How is this being handled, memory-wise?

Comment: No, the result is an `int` in your `int` function. `sum/size` is an **integer division** if both operands are integers.

Comment: @Sjoseph No it doesn't have to store the double.

Comment: Great - thanks for clearing that up. I will look into integer division in C

Comment: @Sjoseph nothing special, it's the same old integer division you learn early in school :) `5 / 3 = 1` (and for the remainder `5 % 3 = 2`).

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with memory. You need to read about arithmetic types in C. With one function computations are made only with integers, while in the other floating points are involved (not the same arithmetic).

Comment: I thought it was memory related as int's and double require different memory allocation?

Comment: @Sjoseph how much memory a representation of `int` and `double` needs is *implementation defined*, but typically, a `double` needs more space. But apart from that, your assumption that your `int` function somewhere creates a `double` value was just wrong.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I understand now - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the int function is performing the calculation, does it still have to store the number as a double, before returning the int?

This question seems to assume that the result of the following line:

```
return sum/size;
```

is always a floating point. But this assumption is wrong. See for example

**C11 (draft N1570), §6.5.6 p6**:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any
>   fractional part discarded.

So, if both operands have an *integer* type, you just get an *integer division*, the result is an integer type, in your example `int` (with a value that just *discards* any fractional part).

---

In your other function, one operand is already a `double`. Have a look at

**C11 (draft N1570) §6.3.1.8 p1**:

> [...]
>   Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `double`.

So in this case, your `size` is implicitly converted to `double` and therefore `/` performs a *floating point division*, the result is a `double`.

Comment: @Sjoseph And to be explicit, it has _nothing_ to do with memory allocation. It's purely integer/integer vs. double/integer division

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on

1.Size of integer on your platform (Compiler Specific).

2.The way in which your compiler+processor supports floating point arithmetic. Floating point arithmetic could be emulated by your compiler if your processor doesn't have FPU.

Consider Below Points:

Assuming for your platform `double` needs more bytes than `integer`:
Stack Usage will be more in `getMean2`function.

Assuming your processor don't have FPU: Text(Code) Segment will consume more memory in `getMean2` function.

`return sum/size;`
will be a integer division in  `getMean1` and it will be a floating point division in `getMean2`

Note:
As you are neither allocating memory dynamically nor you are having global variables your `data` segment and `heap` will be unaffected.